# What's the way to provide suggestion to Ubuntu team

Tags: server

I like Ubuntu,but I'm new to the Linux scene. What is the best way to provide feedback / suggestion to Ubuntu team. So my suggestion / ideas could possibly be looked into in next release. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can give your feedback and ideas [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ContributeToUbuntu#Giving_Ideas_and_Feedback)

Comment: I looked at the link you suggested above and it really doesn't go to a place where you can give feedback . . it goes to link after link with no real place to leave feedback.